# Sharepoint soap using php

Tags: php, sharepoint, soap

Does it possible to use soap php5 from Linux to request Sharepoint?
Does it possible to have a wsdl php?

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you wan't to use [these webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx) from an linux based system makinmg use of php's WSDL web service consuming features. Since php is pretty error tolerant I think you'll have an easy time accessing Sharepoint data.

On the other hand, when passing data to the web service be aware of the typelesness of php which can course trouble in intersystem communication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Let's say you want to do a basic operation, like reading a SharePoint List from PHP. The easiest way i found to access SharePoint's Lists Web Services from PHP is to:

1. Manually download the Lists.asmx file in a folder accessible by your PHP server. This way you'll avoid dealing with the NTLM authentication of your SharePoint site (you'll use basic auth instead). The URL to your WSDL should look like: sharepointsite.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL
2. Use the NuSOAP library to invoke the Web Service, which is by my experience easier to use with the SharePoint Web Services than PHP's own SOAP implementation.

Here's an exemple of the above steps (code sample): [Reading a SharePoint list with PHP](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Here you have a similar question and the answers. I successfully tried with the SOAP method of PHP5 and it works great:

[Connect to Sharepoint Database through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782645/connect-to-sharepoint-database-through-php)