# Not able to connect Php application with SharePoint

Tags: php, linux, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wsdl

I am a php developer have no experience with Share Point. I have follow these two links to get Data from Share Point into my Php application.

1. stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545824/how-to-connect-sharepoint-with-php).
2. A Library for Share Point [here](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API).

Share Point team give me 2 **IP address**. What they said is, I have to **login at Forti Client** with first IP then second IP is used to access application in browser which is also prompted for **Credentials**. If I not login in Forti Client with first IP, Web Application will not work at all. One more thing is, **this process is working well in windows system but not working on ubuntu (Linux)**.

So, My Php applications are running on AWS linux ( ec-tier ). I have to get data from Share Point.

**I just want to know is it possible to get data from Share Point into my application.**

**If it is possible then what is the process that I should follow in order to get data.**

Kindly help me with your suggestions/answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these links help you out.

Forti Client CLI for Linux [click here](https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/).

Shell Script To Use CLI [click here](http://euer.krebsco.de/scripting-the-fortigate-vpn-client.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is it a SharePoint List or Document library?
If it's a list, use web API to call for the required info.
Refer to my answer in this post:
[how to add a connection to a sharepoint list to a word addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201177/how-to-add-a-connection-to-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-word-addin/41207663#41207663)