# how to add a connection to a sharepoint list to a word addin

Tags: list, sharepoint

how to add a connection to a sharepoint list to a word addin?

I'm trying to follow the word-addin microsoft InvoiceManagerSample and where they show the static data, I want to replace this data with the contents of a sharepoint list.

what I need is some sample code to get to the list or some links to get the information from.

I've searched the forums and other places with little success.

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to use SharePoint web API in order to get the information you require.
For this you'll need to refer to the following address in your SP site:
http://yoursitename/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
With this method you can retrieve information from sharepoint lists.
For more info go to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.aspx

Comment: Thanks Adi Solar; will try that next. will this work with Office 365?

Comment: Not sure, I only have on premises experience.

Comment: You should mark it as answer, so that people will know they can find a solution here.

Comment: Adi; I don't know how to mark an answered question as answered or close the topic. I can't ask questions as I've been banned from asking dumb questions. I need to close all of my questions to see if I can get out of the dog house. apparently I pissed somebody off....

Comment: @LuisCarlosRodriguez [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583)