# Access SharePoint file behind company authorization from PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint

I need to access specific file at company sharepoint from PHP.

When I try to access the file via browser, I'm asked for username. I enter my company email address (myId@company.com) and I'm redirected to company login page where I'm asked for company credentials (domain username and password). After login, I'm redirected back to sharepoint where I can access the file.

Is it even possible to follow this process in PHP?

I was trying to login using php-spo library with no luck. Also I have 2 usernames - email using as initial login to sharepoint and domain credentails using to login at the company login page.

Comment: You might be able to use cURL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545824/how-to-connect-sharepoint-with-php might be helpful